# how to get display independent distance between two touch coordinates?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-graphview

I am making multitouch based android app. In the app I am finding distance between two touch coordinates.The Distance between two touch coordinates are same on different devices, but devices show different distance.

Devices A shows 89.0123.

Device B shows 110.84940.

How to get same distance on different devices?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
 int maskedAction=event.getActionMasked();
 switch(maskedAction)
 /// some code
 ///case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN;
 /// 
 PointF init_p1,init_p2;
 init_p1.x=event.getX(0);
 init_p1.y=event.getY(0);
 init_p2.x=event.getX(1);
 init_p2.y=event.getY(1);
 /////// some code
 float X_diff=init_p1.x-init_p2.x;
 float Y_diff=init_p1.y-init_p2.y;
 double xdiffsq= Math.pow(X_diff,2);
 double ydiffsq= Math.pow(Y_diff,2);
 distance=Math.sqrt(xdiffsq+ydiffsq);
 Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(distance));
///some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "the same distance" you mean the same physical distance, then it's because your devices have different screen [densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html). You need to convert your distance (which is currently given is pixels) to density-independent units.

You may use this method:

```
static float pxToDp(Context context, float px) {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, px, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

It should return the same DP values for different screens.

Comment: Again same problem, shows different values on different devices.

Comment: I measured densities of both devices. Both devices have same Density 240.  float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi